# mongoDB querying nested documents within a nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm having problems accessing user.info.name.familyName in a query. I'm newish to database design and queries and I don't know if its possible.

So here is the schema I have. Perhaps it might need to be redesigned for what I'm trying to do to work.

```
var UserSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    emailVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    info: {
        name: {
            givenName: String,  
            familyName: String,
        },
        address: {
            street: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zipCode: String
        },
        primaryPhone: String,
        cellPhone: String,
        website: String,
        licenseNumber: String,
        title: String,
        company: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
        default: '/images/avatar/default/contacts-128.png'
    },
    friends: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: User }],
    friendRequests: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: User }]
});
```

I have a search function that currently searches by username or email and works fine, but I'd like it to also search by the users givenName or familyName. Here is the search function...

```
module.exports.search = function(searchValue, callback) {
    var searchValue = new RegExp(`^${searchValue}`, 'i');
    var query = {
        $or: [
            {username: searchValue}, 
            {email: searchValue}
         // {givenName condition here...}
        ]
    }

    User.find(query, callback).limit(10);
}
```

I tried this... and it didn't work

```
{info.name.givenName: searchValue}
```

I tried a few other nonsensical things but they also failed...

So to summarize my question, how would I either restructure the schema or query to be able to check the searchValue against user.info.name.givenName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
{'info.name.givenName': searchValue}
```

notice the quotes.

You were close :)